# How to pass form data to another page in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've created a login page like this:

```js
class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.container1}>
            <TextInput
              style={{ width: 190, color: 'white' }}
              placeholder="User Name"
              placeholderTextColor="#f9f9f9"
              underlineColorAndroid="#f9f9f9"
            />
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Password"
              secureTextEntry
              returnKeyType="go"
              ref={input => (this.passwordInput = input)}
              style={{ width: 190, color: 'white' }}
              placeholderTextColor="#f9f9f9"
              underlineColorAndroid="#f9f9f9"
            />

            <TouchableOpacity style={{ top: 10 }}>
              <Button
                color="#314561"
                onPress={() => navigate('HomePage')}
                title="Login"
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default Login
```

Now I need to pass the username to the home page. I've referred a number of resources and didn't got any solutions. How can I pass the username to home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First save your input value to some variables using onChangeText

```
<TextInput
value= {this.state.userName}
onChangeText = {(text)=>{
this.setState({userName:text});
}
 />
```

Then you can pass the value ,

```
<Button 
 onPress={() => navigate('HomePage',{"userName":this.state.userName})} // you can pass objects
  title="Login"
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userName:"",
      password:""
    };
  }
  updateUserName = (name) =>{
     this.setState({
      userName:name,
     })
  }
  updatePwd = (pwd) =>{
     this.setState({
      password:pwd,
     })
  }   
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.container1}>
            <TextInput
              style={{ width: 190, color: 'white' }}
              placeholder="User Name"
              placeholderTextColor="#f9f9f9"
              underlineColorAndroid="#f9f9f9"
              onChangeText={(name) => this.updateUserName(name)}
              value={this.state.userName}               
            />
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Password"
              secureTextEntry
              returnKeyType="go"
              ref={input => (this.passwordInput = input)}
              style={{ width: 190, color: 'white' }}
              placeholderTextColor="#f9f9f9"
              underlineColorAndroid="#f9f9f9"
              onChangeText={(pwd) => this.updatePwd(pwd)}
              value={this.state.password}   
            />

            <TouchableOpacity style={{ top: 10 }}>
              <Button
                color="#314561"
                onPress={() => navigate('HomePage',{userName:this.state.userName})}
                title="Login"
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default Login
```

file : homePage.js

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    var data = params.userName;     
    this.state = {
      userName : data
    };
  }
```

Comment: I'm not storing username and password in the state.

Comment: you need to store your username value, then only you can able to access username in homePage.

Comment: No Problem. I will help you.

Comment: Error in Home page : undefined is not an object(evaluating 'params.data')

Comment: sorry, i forgot to update data to userName. Now check code for homePage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163464/discussion-between-sathish-sundharam-and-ajithes111).

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes :

In Login component :

**Username Field**

```
<TextInput 
          style={{width:190,color:'white'}} 
          placeholder="User Name" 
          placeholderTextColor="#f9f9f9" 
          underlineColorAndroid='#f9f9f9'
          onChangeText=
            {(username)=>this.setState({username})}
/>
```

**Button :**

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{top:10}}>
        <Button 
          color="#314561" 
          onPress={() => navigate('HomePage'), { username: this.state.username }} 
          title="Login"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

In Home component:

e.g. `render method`

```
  render(){
      const {state} = this.props.navigation;
      console.og(state.params.username)
    }
```

**Update :**
In login constructor,initialise `state`

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {};
}
```

Comment: Hey, you need to store your username in the state.

Comment: Please add `super` statement  at the begining.Please  see update